# how to use strcat with an ENUM?

Tags: c++, enums, char, strcat

I have an external tool which is generating an ENUM based on user inputs. Now this ENUM is being used by my C++ code where in i have to select a particular ENUM based on a variable say 'x'. The ENUMS generated are of the form 'ENUM_1', 'ENUM_2', 'ENUM_3'....so on. Now I want the code inside my code such that the appropriate ENUM is chosen based on 'x'. I tried using the strcat function like:

```
typedef enum ( enum_1, enum_2, enum_3...enum_n) map1;

y=(map1)strcat("enum_", x);
```

but it gives me the error "Cannot convert from char* to map1.

Can someone pls suggest a method of achieving this.

ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using `strcat`. From the description what I understand is that you want to convert `x` to `map1`. To achieve this, you can do `map1 m = (map1)(x-1);` See this sample code:

```
typedef enum { enum_1, enum_2, enum_3} map1;

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    map1 m = (map1)(x-1);
}
```

`-1` is required because, the integer value of the enums in `map1` starts from 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Well you can't do it this way...

Enums aren't evaluated by name at compile time. You'll have to try something with the preprocessor. You can create a define to do something similar. Something like:

```
#define fn(x) enum_##x
```

And then call

```
fn(x)
```

But this happens when the file gets preprocessed. So you can't access runtime variables. Judging by your code I don't think you'll be able to do what you want.
Good luck though.

Comment: Name mangling does not apply to enum values, nor is it done by the preprocessor. That is probably the trick he wants, though…

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want the code inside my code such that the appropriate ENUM is chosen based on 'x'.

Enumerated values are **constants** and based on the statement I assume that `x` is an integer data type.

```
y=(map1)strcat("enum_", x);
```

strcat(..) passing parameters should be of type `char*`. And clearly `x` is not of type `char*` based on previous statement. It not clear why are you using `strcat` for achieving this task.

Answer for your subject line: **No.** You cannot use strcat with enumerated values.